# message.channel.awaitmessages() filter not working with constant id

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have this command that is supposed to only accept user inputs from me.
I am trying to use this code but there is nothing in the console.

```js
me = await client.users.fetch("< my id >")
mee = msg
mee.author = me
let filter = m => m.author.id === mee.author.id
msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 50000, errors: 
   ['time'], })
      .then(async (collected) => {
      mesg = collected.first
      console.log(mesg.content)
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

There's really no reason to be fetching a user if the only thing you need is their ID - which you're already using for the `fetch` itself.

What you're currently trying to do - overriding the `author` of an existing message - doesn't really make much sense.

Your filter can (likely) be simplified down to the following.

```js
let filter = m => m.author.id === "<your id>"
```